# GoogleInc.:GoogleAPIs:19 is not a valid android target platform

Tags: android, windows, macos, cocos2d-x

The project was first developed in windows, but it change to mac now. I am getting this error:

> GoogleInc.:GoogleAPIs:19 is not a valid android target platform.

when I run `cocos compile -p android`. I installed the Google API 19, but still get this error. Cocos2d-x version is 3.5, and use android-ndk-r9d.

Comment: Android sdk tool is 25.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason, I delete proguard-project.txt,local.properties and project.properties, and then run *android update project --path . --subprojects --target android-19*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the location of the SDK according to what is on your computer
And change the VERISION SDK